# Why do some online Python compilers not allow me to enter an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I found quite a few examples of how to use `input` in Python 3. I even directly copied examples from videos to online python compilers and I always get an EOF error on the input line.

For example:

```
password = input("please enter password... ")
```

it won't even let me put an input and end the program. Did a rule change?

Comment: That code is valid. Are you sure you included both quotation marks? Which specific online compiler are you using?

Comment: The only way that would fail is if you were in an environment where stdin was not hooked up.

Comment: I am positive! i used, tutorialspoint.com and onecompiler.com

Comment: For onecompiler.com, there is a box on the right side where you put the input value _**before you press Run**_. There is no prompt for you to pass in the input while the program is running.

Comment: works ok : https://onecompiler.com/python/3xt83s4uy

Comment: See if it works locally

Answer (score 4):

No, the `input` rules did not change.

It's just those type of online Python interpreters expect you to provide the input values ***before you actually run the program***. There is no prompt for the input value, where they wait for you to enter something. Instead, they automatically read what you put for STDIN and then pass it to your program.

In https://onecompiler.com:

> OneCompiler's python online editor supports stdin and users can give inputs to programs using the STDIN textbox under the I/O tab.

[image: onecompiler example]

In https://www.tutorialspoint.com:

[image: tutorialspoint example 1]

[image: tutorialspoint example 2]

---

I would say it's better to learn how to run your programs *locally*, especially if you are writing programs that get or read multiple user inputs. For example, in the images above, you'll have to add some unnecessary code to print out the name on a separate line or to handle multiple `input`'s. On local, the same code works (and looks) better:

```
$ cat main.py
name = input("What's your name? ")
print(name)

$ python3 main.py
What's your name? gino
gino
```